# Add function arguments in iteration

Tags: functions, function-construction, iterators

I have a list which has the number of n.

```
list={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,...xn}
```

when I use these elements as arguments of a function f[x],
I want to express function with iteration which is similar to `NestList`.
According to the value of n, the arguments of the function are determined by the rule below.

[image]

Any ideas for this? Thanks.

Comment: If the list has length `n` where do the other arguments come from? For example, if `n = 2` the list is `{x1, x2}` but you say that `f` should be `f(x1, x2, x3)`. Where does `x3` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fold1, folds2, fold3, fold4]

fold1  = List @@ Partition[# @@ #2, Length@#2, 2, -1, {}] &;

fold2[f_, l_] := f[## & @@ l[[;; #]]] & /@ Range[1, Length@l, 2]

fold3 = Extract[#2, List /@ Range[Range[1, Length@#2, 2]], Function[k, # @@ k]] &;

fold4 = # @@@ Extract[#2, List /@ Range[Range[1, Length @ #2, 2]]]&;
```

Examples:

```
fold1[f, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

> {f[x1], f[x1, x2, x3], f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}

```
fold1[f, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}]
```

> {f[x1], f[x1, x2, x3], f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7]}

```
(fold1[f, #] ==  fold2[f, #] == fold3[f, #] == fold4[f, #])&[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}]
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

Another one:

```
list = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
f @@@ FoldList[Flatten@*List, list[[{1}]], Rest@list][[;; ;; 2]]
```

And another:

```
Block[{f}
, SetAttributes[f, Flat]
; FoldList[f, f /@ list][[;; ;; 2]]
]
```

> ```
> {f[x1], f[x1, x2, x3], f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

my original answer was unnecessarily complicated. A `Table` command is all what is needed

```
k = 4;(*must be <= 2*n-1 where n is length of list below*)
list = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
Clear[f]
Flatten@Table[f[Sequence @@ list[[1 ;; (2 i - 1)]]], {i, Range[k]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original**

```
k = 4; (*must be <= 2*n-1 where n is length of list below*)
list = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7};
Clear[f]
Flatten@MapIndexed[ {z = First[#2];
    f[Sequence @@ list[[1 ;; (2 z - 1)]]]} &, Range[k]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here we just need to specify `n`. The list of variables is built by `Array`, and then the mapping `#` generates the arguments of `f`. The `List->Sequence` removes extra brackets { } that would otherwise appear in the argument of `f`.

```
n = 4;
list = Array[x, 2 n - 1]; 
(f[list[[1 ;; 2 # - 1]]] /. List -> Sequence) & /@ Range[n]

{f[x[1]], f[x[1], x[2], x[3]], f[x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]], 
     f[x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]]}
```